# Whats wrong with my razor here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am coding under razor 3 and mvc 5.

Here is a `foreach` I have written in a view:

```
@if (TempData["ImageNames"] != null)
{
    List<string> fileNames = (List<string>)TempData["ImageNames"];
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames.ToList())
    {
        <p>@fileName</p>
    }
}
```

the list is not empty but nothing printed.

What could be wrong?

**Update**

Here is the full Html part:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="min-height: 215px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">Upload File</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="/document/upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            </form>
            <hr />
            @{List<string> fileNames = (List<string>)TempData["ImageNames"];}
            @if (TempData["ImageNames"] != null)
            {
                foreach (var fileName in fileNames.ToList())
                {
                    <p>@fileName</p>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Another Update**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Pdf/"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
    PdfReader reader = null;
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;
    List<string> pdfNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> imageNames = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        reader = new PdfReader(path);
        for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string fileName1 = guid+ ".pdf";
            string fileName2 = guid + ".png";
            pdfNames.Add(fileName1);
            imageNames.Add(fileName2);
            string path1 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Pdf/temp/"), fileName1);
            document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex));
            pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(document,new System.IO.FileStream(path1, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, pageIndex);
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(importedPage);
            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            document.Close();
            PDFDocument pdfDoc = new PDFDocument();
            pdfDoc.LoadPDF(path1);
            Bitmap pngImage = pdfDoc.ToImage(0);
            string path2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Pdf/temp/"), fileName2);
            pngImage.Save(path2, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    TempData["ImageNames"] = imageNames;
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the list is not empty?

Comment: @Andrei Of course by setting a breakpoint on the casting line.

Comment: Ok, than the next question - have you checked the final markup? Maybe results are printed, but hidden from the view?

Comment: Can please show us the view code?

Comment: @Andrei And even there is nothing printed in the final markup.

Comment: @HamidReza Is its entering into the loop and see what the fileName is?

Comment: Did you check before or after the cast? And that `.ToList()` isn't helping anything anymore.

Comment: Here is fiddle that works perfect. https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ZB8Zo you might need to use `@Html.Raw()`

Comment: Post the code that fills `TempData["ImageNames"]`

Comment: @user2773448 Yes I can see the file name in debug mode but its not rendered in html.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I checked it and it had 9 items. I know that .ToList() wont help at all but it is my last try after passing many ways to solve it.

Comment: It might be caching issue so try deleting cookies or in private browsing mode to ensure data is not from cache.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I tried it in 3 different machines.

Comment: @HamidReza - did you look at the output in the browser, between  the `<hr />` and the `</div>` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes. Nothing like a <p> was there!

Comment: The declaration of `fileNames` looked a lot better in the initial sample than in  the  full Html part update.

Comment: are you sure there is nothing wrong with the classes that are wrapping around this part? also try to print something like 'test' outside of foreach as a plain string <text>test</text> , see if it prints

Comment: @MandarJogalekar It didnt worked.

Comment: if it's still unsolved, try to remove all div's around it to see what happens? Only keep list printing part in code.

Answer (score 0):

May be my syntax will be little wrong because I cannot open visual studio in here but as far as I know for show the variables at UI you need the put ":" before your variables.So the code will be like this:

```
@if (TempData["ImageNames"] != null)
{
   List<string> fileNames = (List<string>)TempData["ImageNames"];
   foreach (var fileName in fileNames.ToList())
   {
      <p>@:fileName</p>
   }
}
```

Comment: What about converting TempData["ImageNames"] to list. May be foreach loop didnt start for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Humour me and try doing:

```
@{
    if (TempData["ImageNames"] != null) {
        List<string> fileNames = (List<string>)TempData["ImageNames"];
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            <p>@Html.Raw(fileName)</p>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your list is empty then.

Comment: Easy to verify and zoom in on the issue with `<p>Hello 1</p>`  statements at various points in the if/foreach logic.

Comment: @Sippy No its not empty.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried <p>@fileNames[0]</p> but nothing printed.

Comment: Try to print some constants, that tell you that you entered the loop and exited the @If() etc.

Answer (score 0):

`<text>@fileName</text>` ,use this i hope it work.